# Azure's node Deploy uses wrong Node and NPM

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, npm

When I deploy to Azure WebSite the node runtime correctly uses the Nodejs I config in package.json, however the deployment script uses the node and NPM on the server's path. (The Server path is messed up and has both node version in the path.)

Ex. I want nodejs 4.2.1 and NPM >2

When I deploy an app it uses 0.10.x and NPM 1.x.x. My rxjs module requires NPM > 2 so it fails to load.

If I deploy avoiding the packages I can see the correct runtime is run.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply customize the nodejs version in [Azure manage portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/).

In **CONFIGUE** tab of your web site portal, under the **APP SETTINGS** section, the nodejs version is set as `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `0.10.32` by Azure default, we can directly change it value to `4.2.1` you want.

Click the restart button at bottom nav bar after you modified the site setting.

Login on your KUDU console site, you can check the nodejs version in the cmdlet.(The site URL should be: `https://{your site name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`)

And the nodejs version is 4.2.1 with npm version 3.3.9 after modification.

You can get more info at [Specifying a Node.js version in an Azure application](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-specify-node-version-azure-apps/#versioning-websites-with-app-settings).

Comment: Thanks. I had done that, but I set it to 4.2.0 which that version was not on azure. Setting to 4.2.1 did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are also atleast [two other mentions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/04/20/nodejs-and-npm-versions-on-azure-app-services/) on various sources claiming that it can be set via package.js:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 8.2.0 || 8.x.x",
    "npm": ">= 5.3.0 || 5.x.x"
  },
```

Or via the iisnode.yaml file in the site directory root. Which one does the trick is really hard to discover since you can only tell the node version correctly during runtime of the app.